# Disable system restore vista and delete all previous restore points?

Tags: windows-vista, system-restore

How can I delete previous system restore points in vista to free up disk space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was covered by our friends over at howtogeek.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-system-restore-in-windows-vista/

When you disable system restore, all previous restore points are deleted.

Comment: This link is not for Vista anymore in spite of the wording in the URL. Please include the instructions rather than just linking as websites do remove/change their content.

Actually, just found an answer you did that does include it: https://superuser.com/questions/101498/how-to-disable-system-restore-in-vista-home-premium#answer-101501

Thanks.