# How to disable System Restore in Vista Home Premium

Tags: windows-vista, system-restore

The "System Protection" tab is not available in Vista Home Premium and Gpedit.msc is not present to activate it. Are there any registry settings I can edit to enable this tab?

I would like to clear prior system restore points so that spyware can't be restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the registry. Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT` create a new key called **SystemRestore** (if one isn't already there), below that key create a new DWORD value called **DisableConfig** and set it to **1**.

Comment: This didn't work, the tab still isn't there, and all the restore points are. I'll advise the user to not perform a system restore from a restore point earlier than x.

Comment: This won't delete the restore points but rather turn off the feature so it doesn't make more in the future.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-system-restore-in-windows-vista/

Our friends over at How-To-Geek created a great tutorial for this. Check it out. This covers windows 7 and Vista.

> Disable on Windows Vista
>
> Once you’ve clicked the System Protection link in Control Panel, you’ll see the checkboxes next to your different disks:
>
> [image]
>
> Once you uncheck the drive, click the “Turn System Restore Off” button.
>
> [image]

Comment: you posted a Windows 7 Screenshot, Vista is different. and eric said the System Protection tab is not present. :)

Comment: @Molly: Yep, I was in the middle of getting the pictures to work and linked the wrong one at first.